# can someone explain how this call function works in this method

Tags: aurelia

On line 31 here --> https://github.com/benib/aurelia-hammer/blob/master/src/hammer-press.js

```
this.callback.call(null, { hammerEvent: event });
```

Can someone explain how this hammerEvent object gets mapped back to the $event object in the calling aurelia view model?

Comment: Do you mean when the attribute is consumed?

Comment: The indicated line forwards the parameter that the containing method receives (`event`) as a property of the object passed to the callback. The invoking expression in the view specifies a value for the argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain how this hammerEvent object gets mapped back to
>   the **$event** object in the calling **aurelia view model**?

There are a few things happening to get there.

Say you're using it in your view like so:

```
<div hammer-tap.call="handleTap($event)">
</div>
```

1. When compiling the `hammer-tap` attribute, `aurelia-templating-binding` will go through a list of conventions to [map the binding attributes](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/blob/master/src/syntax-interpreter.js#L29) to the correct expressions.
2. Based on the convention for `.call` as you can see in [syntax-interpreter](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-binding/blob/master/src/syntax-interpreter.js#L111), it's translated to a `CallExpression` (located in `aurelia-binding`)
3. When compilation is done and `bind()` is invoked on the components, this `CallExpression` [sets a delegate on the target](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/src/call-expression.js#L54) that invokes `callSource` with whatever value it gets from the target (in your example: `{ hammerEvent: event }`

Now it's a little tricky to fully cover this because of the depth and recursion in how Aurelia resolves all of this, but somewhere along the line a [ListenerExpression](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/src/listener-expression.js) is created (`createBinding` is invoked by [ViewFactory](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/view-factory.js#L139) in `aurelia-templating)` which essentially adds an event listener to the element in question.

5. That `ListenerExpression` would invoke hammer's `handleSwipe` method with the correct event.

I believe that's not actually what happens in this particular scenario, because the author seems to use `hammerjs`'s [own event handler](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/src/manager.js#L220) with `.on` and `.off`. So it would actually be `hammerjs` passing that event to `handleSwipe` from a regular event listener.

6. Back to `CallExpression`, `callSource` will ultimately invoke the function that was bound to `.call` and pass in the `$event` that it received from `ListenerExpression` (or `hammerjs`'s handler) earlier.

Hopefully, this was somewhat helpful. But as you can see, it's quite involved :)

Comment: Thanks Fred! I think I was over thinking this but your answer helped connect the dots. Appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript functions can be called via `call` method , reason functions can be a variable.

```
var p = function(x)
{
    console.log('calling via Call method. arguments: ' + x);
}
```

Now if I want to call this function , one way to call this is using call method as below.

```
p.call(null,'test')
```

more details on call function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

I think wiring up the objects and maps are done in hammer js `inputHandler` and `computeInputData`

https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js

Hope that helps !

Comment: The ability for functions to be stored as variables, passed as parameters to functions, or returned from functions is referred to as a language's capability for [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Comment: I don't think OP asked for a general explanation on how javascript functions can be called.

Comment: I realized that later...sorry

Answer (score -1):

Javascript provide three ways of a calling a function

1. The simple way,

Suppose you have a function

```
function foo() {

}
```

and you simply call it with parenthesis like `foo()`

2. By using `call` method of `Function.prototype`

All right, consider the `foo` function again

But this time you need to see it in a different way, every function in javascript is also an object and every object has a prototype which can then have more functions and properties. So when you define a function like that `foo` it also becomes an object of `Function` and gives you two additional methods to call the function, one of them is `call` which expects first argument to be the context or `this` and then comma separated list of arguments which you want to pass to function. For example, you have a user object which have properties `firstName` and `lastName` and you want to have function which will say something to that user, you can define the function like this

```
function saySomething(something) {
 return "Hey " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName} + " I wanted to say " + something
}
```

3. By using `apply` method of `Function.prototype`

Very much similar to `call` except instead of giving comma separated args you will pass an array.

More on this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: How does this answer OP's question regarding how the HammerEvent object gets mapped back to the Aurelia $event object?